# Reporting services display data format help

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a Tablix and my query returns 5 records. Here is my query results. Please let me know how to display them. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
2      Test1            20
3      Test2            30
4      Test3            40
5      Test4            50
```

I have to display in the following format on the report.

```
Title        
-------------------------------------
obj1:   Test1                Percentage: 20
obj2:   Test2                Percentage: 30
obj3:   Test3                Percentage: 40
obj4:   Test4                Percentage: 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this. The example was created in SSRS 2008 R2.

The example assumes that you have created a data source and created a report using the wizard with the help of a query.

This is the table structure I have used for this example.

[image: Table]

Following query was used in the report and also the table records are shown.

[image: Query]

Now, you have a report like this with each of your columns displayed separately in the report.

[image: Base report]

Right-click on the first column and select Expression...

[image: Select Expressions]

Enter the expression `="Obj" + Cstr(Fields!Id.Value) + ":" + StrDup(10, " ") + Fields!Obj.Value + StrDup(10, " ") + "Percentage: " + CStr(CInt(Fields!Percentage.Value))`

This query uses `CStr` to convert integers to string. I have used `CInt` for the numeric field to drop off the decimals. The function `StrDup` is to duplicate the space 10 times. You can specify the number to determine how many spaces you need.

[image: Expression]

Right-click on the column **Obj** and select `Delete Columns`.

[image: Obj column]

Right-click on the column **Percentage** and select `Delete Columns`.

[image: Percentage column]

Expand the column Id and change the title text to Title. Run the report and here is the output.

[image: Output]

Hope that helps.